# Where to set environment variables for non interactive bash use?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I add an `export` declaration in `~/.bashrc` the environment variable is available only if I use `bash` interactively, not when I invoke a command as argument to bash, e.g. `bash -c export`.

Where do I set environment variables so that they are available both in interactive and non-interactive mode?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170493/login-non-login-and-interactive-non-interactive-shells